# Movie clip editing - Rotoscoping output

Tags: transparency, image, movie-clip-editor, output

I have output frames from the Movie editor as PNG before with transparent background but cannot remember the settings. I can only now get the required image with a Black background even though RGBA is elected in the output panel. Has something changed with v3.5?
I do not want to use the compositor for further individual image editing reasons.